# Deleting Everything ever created in Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a command that can delete everything ever created in Oracle 10g so I can start again?

Comment: Are you talking about dropping the schema you are using or actually reinstalling the entire database?

Comment: I dont know what a schema is but i would like to clear every thing i have ever created i will try to explain the best i can every week my uni gives me a tutorial to do and in each tutorial there are a number of create table tasks and populate table tasks and link table tasks ect.... in which i have to compleate we are on week 4 now and i would love to clear or delete everything i have done so far to start again so i can make understanding of oracle thanks for teh quick replys guys

Comment: In which case, what APC said is what you want.

Comment: I am using putty.exe to access oracle 10g from my uni server what is that i have to do to modify this drop user apc cascade / so i can clear everything

Comment: The `apc` in `drop user apc` was just an example. You would replace `apc` with your schema name. But you probably don't have the ability to run `drop user ...` so once you are connected using putty, log into the database using sqlplus like you normally would and run the second bit of code that APC posted. That should clear everything.

Comment: SQLPLUS? i can just view the interface of oracle through putty not sql i dont have anything relating to sql or oracle installed on my machine am accessing oracle through putty from my univiristys server :) the reason i want to clear everything is when i try to drop a table oracle tells me "DROP of nested tables not supported" while the table that was related to was droped fine but there are four tables i want to drop but they give that error therefore i thought to start again thank you for the help

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to clear out a schema would be to log in as a DBA and drop the user:

```
drop user apc cascade
/
```

But if you really want to just drop the objects, you'll need to deploy some dynamic SQL.

```
declare
    stmt varchar2(2000);
begin
    for r in ( select object_type, object_name
               from user_objects
               where object_type in 
                   ( 'TYPE', 'PACKAGE', 'FUNCTION', 'PROCEDURE', 
                      'SEQUENCE', 'VIEW', 'TABLE', 'MATERIALIZED VIEW')
              _
    loop
         stmt :=  'drop '||r.object_type||' '||r.object_name;
         -- to avoid failures due to foreign keys
         if r.object_type = 'TABLE' then
             stmt := stmt || ' cascade constraints';
         end if;
         execute immediate stmt;
     end loop;
end;
```

This should force the dropping of every object in your schema in most scenarios.  But there is a possibility that it will fail (say if some other session has a lock on an object).  Also it doesn't handle dependencies due to TYPE inheritance.  So there are obvious ways it can be improved: automatic re-running, excpetion handling, etc.  But it provides a starter for ten.

---

In the real world, as opposed to the ivory towers of Academe, there should be no need for a procedure like this.  Every database build script should have an equal and opposite regression script.  Sadly this is frequently not the case.

---

> "I dont know what a schema is"

A schema is all the objects owned by a user.  It is indistinguishable from the user in that they share the same name and an empty schema is implicitly created when we create a user.  However, strictly they are two different things.   [Find out more](http://radiofreetooting.blogspot.com/2007/02/user-schema.html).

Comment: I dont know what a schema is but i would like to clear every thing i have ever created i will try to explain the best i can every week my uni gives me a tutorial to do and in each tutorial there are a number of create table tasks and populate table tasks and link table tasks ect.... in which i have to compleate we are on week 4 now and i would love to clear or delete everything i have done so far to start again so i can make understanding of oracle thanks for teh quick replys guys

Answer (score 0):

On a mac 10.5.8, to delete each and every file regarding oracle 10g db instance delete these dirs:
- oracle (the dir generated from the installation procedure)
- oraInventory (common directory for all oracle installation on your system)
- /var/opt/oracle (contains the file that sets the oraInventory dir location)
- db (is the dir unzipped from the file downloaded from oracle site for installation)
- db.zip (the file downloaded from oracle site for intallation)

Now you can fresh install a new oracle database on your mac. At least, this worked for me.

I found useful information [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b25286/pre_install.htm#BABCHAED) and [here](http://blog.rayapps.com/2009/04/12/how-to-install-oracle-database-10g-on-mac-os-x-intel/).